# Not a Valid choice WTFORMS

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

This is my code: First list of choice

```
Countries = [('US', 'United States'),
    ('CA', 'Canada'),
    ('AF', 'Afghanistan'),
    ('AL', 'Albania'),
    ('DZ', 'Algeria'),
    ('AS', 'American Samoa'),...]
```

forms.py

```
class OrganisationForm(Form):
    id = HiddenField('id', default="-1")
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    manager_name = StringField('manager_name')
    address = StringField('address', validators=[DataRequired()])
    city = StringField('city', validators=[DataRequired()])
    postal_code = StringField('postal_code', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=16)])
    province = StringField('province', validators=[Length(max=2, message="Can't exceed 2 characters")])
    country = SelectField('country', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=Countries)
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
    cancel = SubmitField('Cancel')
```

my model.py:

```
class Organisation(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, unique=True)
  invoices = db.relationship('Invoice', backref='organisation',lazy='dynamic', cascade="all, delete-orphan")
  manager_name = db.Column(db.String)
  address = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  city = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  province = db.Column(db.String(2), nullable=False)
  country = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
  postal_code = db.Column(db.String(16), nullable=False)
```

and template.htm:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="content-section">
  {{ utils.flashed_messages() }}
  <div class="center">

      {% if add_orgnisation %}
                <h3>add an organisation</h3>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                {{ wtf.quick_form(form,novalidate=True) }}
            {% else %}
                <h3>Edit an organisation</h3>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
      {% endif %}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form,novalidate=True) }}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I don t understand why my Selectfield for countries give me a validation error :Not a valid choice...?

I tried to add coerce=tuple but it is not working.
I feel that countries topple is the issue but don't know how to solve.

thanks for your help

Comment: This looks correct to me. Can you try adding `validate_choice=False` to the `SelectField` and let me know what gets saved to the field when a choice is selected?

Comment: It save country CA for Canada, US for USA...

Comment: And just so we're on the same page, when you remove `validate_choice=False` (or just set it to True which is the default), and make the same selections, you get a validation error with no saved data, is that correct?